# how to pass parameters into python function bug

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have this piece of code:

```
   points = np.array([[207.0,489.0], [500.0,58.0], [84.0,17.0],[197.0,262.0]])
    #read data from the csv file 
    x = df["XC"]
    y = df["YC"]
    # make the x,y a point type 
    pointP = np.array([x,y])
    #print(pointP)
    rW,rV,rU = calcRatios(points,pointP,ratioU,ratioV,ratioW)
```

and this is the calcRatios function

```
def calcRatios(points,centreP,ratioU,ratioV,ratioW):
    v0 = points[1] - points[0]
    v1 = points[2] - points[0]
    v2 = centreP - points[0]
    #dot product of the vects
    d00 = np.dot(v0, v0)
    d01 = np.dot(v0, v1)
    d11 = np.dot(v1, v1)
    d20 = np.dot(v2, v0)
    d21 = np.dot(v2, v1)
    #calc denom
    denom = d00 * d11 - d01 * d01
    #barycentric ratios of v,w,u
    ratioV = (d11 * d20 - d01 * d21) / denom
    ratioW = (d00 * d21 - d01 * d20) / denom
    ratioU = 1.0 - ratioV - ratioW
    return ratioV,ratioW,ratioU
```

The data from the dataframe is stored like this:

```
       Index      XC      YC    R    G    B
           1       0       0  227  227  227
           2       1       0  237  237  237
           3       2       0   0     0    0
           4       3       0  232  232  232
           5       4       0  233  233  233
...        ...     ...     ...  ...  ...  ...
```

However right now there seems to be an issue with the centreP point that I am passing into the function and I am not sure why.

The error I get says : `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,28686) (2,)` for this line  `v2 = centreP - points[0]`

Could someone tell me why this is happening and how it should be fixed?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the value of `df["XC"]` and `df["YC"]`?

Comment: @haccks I printed out pointP and   [[0   1   2 ... 504 505 506]
 [  0   0   0 ... 508 508 508]] this is what I get. I wanted it to be saved as [x,y] points.

Comment: This won't do what you are expecting. Use list comprehensions to make list of points out of the two lists.

Comment: @haccks made an edit to show the dataframe :)

Comment: @haccks how would it be done it using list comprehensions? not sure about how that works. thanks!

Comment: Do you want points to be an array of 2 elements of something else?

Comment: @haccks yeah like [x1,y1], [x2,y2], [x3,y3] etc. Pairs of the coordinates for the whole list.

Comment: Did it solve the problem?

Comment: What do you expect `centreP - points[0]` to be? What shape array and can you give the first few values you expected to see?

Comment: @haccks yep :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.array([x,y])` will return an array of arrays, not what you are expecting. If you want to have an array of points out of `x` and `y` then this will do the job

```
pointP = np.array([[a, b] for a, b in zip(x, y)])
```

Comment: It's unnecessary and inefficient to zip together columns from the same dataframe. In general, use `numpy` or `pandas` methods to manipulate and reshape data stored in those formats, rather than converting to lists and then back to an array.

Answer (score 2):

Your `centreP` is an array of two long arrays: `[[0, 1, 2...], [0,0,0...]]`, while `points[0]` is a single array of length 2, `[207.0,489.0]`. numpy's [broadcasting rules](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.broadcasting.html) can't handle subtraction of these two shapes. However if you transpose `centreP` to `[[0,0], [1,0], [2,0]...]` it will handle this by subtracting `points[0]` from each row:

```
 v2 = centreP.T - points[0]
```

Better still, pass `df[[XC, YC]]` instead of `pointP` - it will be coerced to a numpy array in the right shape.

```
rW,rV,rU = calcRatios(points, df[["XC","YC"]]) # no need to transpose
```